# Передать название статьи с кнопкой Твиттера

Tags: twitter, html, javascript

Собственно сабж.
Может быть кто делал уже.
Хотелось бы примерно так: есть название статьи

`<p>Статья для Твиттера</p>`

и чтобы, когда нажимаешь на "твитнуть", передавалось не только URL, но и название статьи видом "Статья для Твиттера http://example.ru".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужна стандартная кнопка, то задаем параметры в data-url и data-text при генерации страницы.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{нужный URL}" data-text="{Название статьи}" data-lang="ru" data-count="none">Твитнуть</a>
```

Если нужен какой-то особый вид кнопки, создай свою кнопку стилизуй как нравится и на  onclick повесь что-то вроде

```
window.open("http://twitter.com/home?status='Статья для Твиттера http://example.ru'")
```

Comment: Там же скрипт стоит Твиттера

Comment: iKuzko, хорошее решение!